# Add meta tags with a plugin?

Tags: plugins, post-meta, homepage

I've tried a number of plugins including Add Meta Tags and Meta SEO Pack which add a meta tag description to the home page.

But my home page is static so the description is added to my blog page.

I know I could add them manually but are there any plugins do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the wp_head() function called in your header.php template file?

Comment: yes I'm building a child theme from thematic so i could use the thematic_create_description() filter - http://themeshaper.com/thematic/guide/?page_id=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone using Thematic, the thematic_create_description() filter worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Yoast SEO Plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/). It will help you to do many things and also much more which you don't know about their importance.

Comment: Please do not leave links to your own website under your posts. This can be considered spam.

Comment: Ok. I was new member that is way i did not know about it.